# Covariant type parameter

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, covariance

I have been trying to push my understanding of Scala a little bit further lately and I cannot really figure out some things about covariant/contravariant type parameters.

Let's say I have a class called `Basket` as follows :

```
class Basket[+A <: Fruit](items: List[A]) {
  // ...
  def addAll[B >: A <: Fruit](newItems: List[B]): Basket[B] =
new Basket(items ++ newItems)
  // ...
}
```

and some classes like this:

```
trait Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit
```

---

I know for sure that these assertions are correct :

- `Basket[Fruit]` can be instantiated
- `Basket[String]` cannot be instantiated (because `String` is not a subtype of `Fruit`)
- `Basket[Banana]` is a subtype of `Basket[Fruit]`
- `Basket[Orange]` is a subtype of `Basket[Fruit]`
- This code:

  ```
  val bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = new Basket(List(new Banana, new Banana))
  bananaBasket.addAll(List(new Orange))
  ```

will return a `Basket[Fruit]`

- This code:

  ```
  val bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = new Basket(List(new Banana, new Banana))
  bananaBasket.addAll(List(new Banana))
  ```

will return a `Basket[Banana]`

---

What I do not understand is how the `B >: A` affects the return type of the method .. Why when I add an `Orange` the return type become `Basket[Fruit]` and when I add a `Banana`, it stays a `Basket[Banana]` ? Does it look for the "lowest" common super-type ?

Comment: What did you find out when you tried compiling your "assertions" and seeing which of them are correct?

Comment: You also need to add `Fruit` as an upper bound to the parameter `B` in `Basket.addAll` method (`addAll[B >: A <: Fruit]...`).

Comment: All the assertions are true. My question was not very clear indeed. I'll edit it.

Comment: "Does it look for the "lowest" common super-type ?" - exactly

Comment: @PeterNeyens Just for information, do you have any idea on why we have to repeat the constraint ?

Comment: Because the compiler cannot use the fact that `Basket` has that upper bound, to constrain `B`, so whenever you create a `Basket[X]` you need to make sure that `X` has `Fruit` as upper bound.

Comment: @PeterNeyens Very clear, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Scala compiler tries to find the lowest common super-type. You can see it anywhere in Scala, including standard library classes. Consider this example for List, which is also covariant on its parameter type:

```
1.0 :: List(1, 2, 3)
// result type is AnyVal, least common ancestor of Double and Int
res1: List[AnyVal] = List(1.0, 1, 2, 3)

"0" :: List(1, 2, 3)
// result type is List[Any], lowest common ancestor of String and Int
res2: List[Any] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)

0 :: List(1, 2, 3)
// result type is List[Int] exactly
res3: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)

res2.head
res4: Any = 0

res2.head.asInstanceOf[String]
res5: String = "0"
```

One can argue this is a dubious feature of Scala type system, because it's easy to end up with something like `Any` (how it's in my example) or `Product with Serializable` (if you're dealing with case classes), and then the error messages are quite misleading.

If you want to restrict Scala from generalizing your types, you should use the "sad in a hat" type constraint `<:<`. Then your code would look like this (I've changed the classes to case classes for readability):

```
case class Banana() extends Fruit
defined class Banana

case class Orange() extends Fruit
defined class Orange

case class Basket[+A <: Fruit](items: List[A]) {
    // ...
    def addAll[B >: A <: Fruit, C >: A](newItems: List[B])(implicit ev: B <:< C): Basket[B] =
  new Basket(items ++ newItems)
    // ...
  }
defined class Basket

val bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = Basket(List(Banana(), Banana()))
bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = Basket(List(Banana(), Banana()))

bananaBasket.addAll(List(Orange())) // not accepted
Main.scala:593: Cannot prove that Product with Serializable with cmd27.Fruit <:< cmd47.Banana.
bananaBasket.addAll(List(Orange()))
                   ^
Compilation Failed

bananaBasket.addAll(List(Banana())) // accepted
res52: Basket[Banana] = Basket(List(Banana(), Banana(), Banana()))
```

You can read more about this pattern in an very informative blog post here: http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html