# Covariance type parameter with multiple constraints

Tags: scala, types, covariance

I am learning the concept of type variance and bounds in scala and how to use them. I came across the below question on stack overflow where one of the solutions mentioned how to prevent scala from generalizing the types.

[Covariant type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102837/covariant-type-parameter)

Below is the code posted in the solution. In the below code, How does adding a new type parameter C help? I understand how B is constrained ( as a supertype of A and subtype of Fruit). But I am completely lost as to what C does here. Why should it be Super type of A. Why does the implicit evidence require B to be subtype of C?

And why there is an irrelevant error when adding List of Orange object that Fruit is not subtype of Banana. Can someone please explain this?

I am guessing to satisfy the first constraint, Orange object is inferred as Fruit object but lost after that as to why it says Fruit is not a subtype of Banana.

```
case class Banana() extends Fruit
defined class Banana

case class Orange() extends Fruit
defined class Orange

case class Basket[+A <: Fruit](items: List[A]) {
    // ...
    def addAll[B >: A <: Fruit, C >: A](newItems: List[B])(implicit ev: B <:< C): Basket[B] =
  new Basket(items ++ newItems)
    // ...
  }
defined class Basket

val bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = Basket(List(Banana(), Banana()))
bananaBasket: Basket[Banana] = Basket(List(Banana(), Banana()))

bananaBasket.addAll(List(Orange())) // not accepted
Main.scala:593: Cannot prove that Product with Serializable with cmd27.Fruit <:< cmd47.Banana.
bananaBasket.addAll(List(Orange()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax

```
def foo[A >: LA <: UA, B...](...)(implicit ev: F[A, B] <:< G[A, B], ...)
```

means that

- firstly `A, B ...` should be inferred so that conditions `A >: LA <: UA, B...` are satisfied and
- secondly for these inferred `A, B ...` conditions `F[A, B] <:< G[A, B], ...` should be checked.

Basically `C >: A` and `ev: B <:< C` mean (since `C` is used nowhere else and compiler is looking for the lowest upper bound for `C`) that `C` is `A` and for it we should check that `B <:< A`. Just we can't remove `C >: A` and replace `ev: B <:< C` with `ev: B <:< A` since then we'll have `Error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type B <:< A of value ev`.

So we want `B` to be inferred so that `B >: A <: Fruit` (i.e. `B` should be a **supertype** of `A`) and for this `B` to check that `B <:< A` (i.e. `B` should be a **subtype** of `A`). So this can be satisfied only when `A = B`. And this prevents `bananaBasket.addAll(List(Orange()))` from compilation.

Comment: @jwvh No, implicits are resolved also at compile time.

Comment: Yes, of course they are. My bad. Then why won't the compiler adjust `C` to `Fruit` which would comply with both restrictions?

Comment: @jwvh `bananaBasket` is a `Basket[Banana]` so `A=Banana`. `newItems: List[B] = List(Orange())` so `B >: Orange` . So minimal `B, C` satisfying `[B >: A <: Fruit, C >: A]` are `B=Fruit, C=A=Banana` and this doesn't satisfy `ev: B <:< C`. Compile error says precisely that: `Error: Cannot prove that App.Fruit <:< App.Banana`. (I made `trait Fruit extends Product with Serializable` to avoid [1](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html)).

Comment: @jwvh Both type inference and implicit resolution occur at compile time but `A,B...` in `[A >: LA <: UA, B...]` are inferred before checking `(implicit ev: F[A, B] <:< G[A, B], ...)`. See examples `def tupleIfSubtype[T <: U, U]` and `def tupleIfSubtype[T, U](t: T, u: U)(implicit ev: T <:< U)` in https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html

Comment: @jwvh These were examples when types are inferred before implicits are resolved. And here is example vice versa when implicit is resolved before type is inferred: `trait Typeclass[T]`
  `implicit val int: Typeclass[Int] = null`
  `def foo[T]()(implicit ev: Typeclass[T]) = ???`
  `foo()`

Comment: @dmytromitin Thanks for the explanation. Now it is clear to me. Could you also please explain why you have used `F[A, B]` and `G[A, B]` in implicit ev? How should I read that and what do they mean? Isn't `B <:<  A` a representation for `<:<[B, A]`?

Comment: @Aandal Yes, `B <:< A` is `<:<[B, A]`. I meant that in `implicit ev` you can check that some type depending on `A, B` (for example it can be `B`) is a subtype of some other type depending on `A,B` (for example it can be `A`).